# Change options of running process

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

Is it possible to change the options of a running process in *nix?

For example, if I SSH into a server and run `zip -rq file.zip public_html` it will begin zipping up the public html folder into file.zip, but it won't give me any output. If I were to SSH into the server a second time while this first command was running, is there a way to change the options (in this example from `-rq` to `-r`)?

I am not looking for an answer specific to the above scenario, but a general answer for any scenario/process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: no

Since command line arguments are usually evaluated at program start, there is now way to do this.

But why don't you directly start your zip command without -q?

You may also redirect the output to a file and read it within another session:

In the first session do:

```
zip -r file.zip public_html >/tmp/ziplog.log
```

In the second session do:

```
tail -f /tmp/ziplog.log
```

Comment: "But why don't you directly start your zip command without -q?" - Didn't want to spam my screen with lots and lots of filenames if public_html contains lots of files/folders (e.g. a Magento build). Alternative Answer: I'm thick.